# Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to login and signup in react. using react-redux, thunk v3.1.0, but getting error
my auth.types.js file include
[image]

Auth.action.js include

[image]

auth.reducer.js include

[image]

store.js has

```
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
```

login.jsx include loginHandle

[image]

how can I solve this error

[image]

Comment: Copy and Paste the code, please

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your code as properly formatted and readable code snippets. See [mcve]. Images of code and text are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable in terms of code/issue reproduction.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the code is attempting to dispatch the `formData` object as an action payload.

```js
const formData = {
  email: data.get("email"),
  password: data.get("password"),
  // <-- no type property!
};

...

loginAPI(dispatch(formData)); // <-- dispatch(formData)!
```

`formData` is an object with an undefined `type` property, thus the error you see.

`loginAPI` is an action creator that is defined to to first receive the `formData` payload and return the asynchronous action, i.e. Thunk, that is passed the store's `dispatch` function.

You should be dispatching the `loginAPI` action to the store.

```js
dispatch(loginAPI(formData));
```

If you would like to wait for the asynchronous `loginAPI` action to complete prior to navigating then you may want to `await` it's settling.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  ...

  try {
    await dispatch(loginAPI(formData));
    navigate("/");
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Be aware also that you are using outdated Redux. Modern Redux is written using [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) which is less boilerplatey and generates a lot of the actions for you so you end up writing ***significantly*** less code.